# How can I level up hunter rank quickly?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I am leveling up my hunter rank and I just recently only hit level 5. A major downside about taking on hunts is that you can only accept one at a time, which is very time consuming and causes it to take [FOREVER](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-Q7b-vHY3Q) to increase.

When going from town to town, I came across a Behemoth hunt at the Chocobo Ranch that required a level 8 hunter rank. It has taken me quite a while to reach level 5 - and it will take even longer to reach level 8 - and I am debating if it is even worth taking the time to increase it that high.

Aside from completing the hunts that give the most stars, are there any tricks to speeding up this process? Or am I stuck in a continual loop of going back-and-forth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, as you've noted, you can only take on a single hunt at any given time. This drastically slows down the process of raising your Hunter Rank.

To make matters even more difficult, based on posts in threads like [this one](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/932981-final-fantasy-xv/74736679), it looks like Hunter stars are a ***finite*** reward and completing every hunt in the game will land you at level 10 *exactly*.

> I've done practically all the bounties, and I cant find anymore to do. Im rank 9. Im 28/43. Am I suppose to do something to unlock more hunter quest? Ive done all the dungeons, done the story, even the pitoss dungeon. What else is there for me to do to reach LVL 10
>
> It's possible that you missed a location for its hunts, I suggest having a checklist of each outpost / town and going to all of them just to confirm you did every hunt at each, I did similar things in games where I thought I did everything, but I just missed one area because the map showed me as having it available so I just assumed I went there.
>
> Don't forget the newly unlocked rank 9 hunts at Hunter HQ. Iirc, they all add up to 15 points. Could very well be what you're missing.

I summed the Stars column in [this chart](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bjqddcIkcOEud3aHtD4qzmKb9HJEdvmDnQ2xvqJmDK8/edit#gid=0) and the result was **293** stars.

From [this list of Hunter Rank requirements](http://www.ign.com/wikis/final-fantasy-15/Hunter_Ranks), the requirements for each level are:

> 5, 15, 30, 50, 40, 40, 40, 30, 43

These add up to **293**, as well. Thus, in order to reach Hunter Rank 10, you will have to complete *every Hunting quest in the game*.

The most optimal method for leveling up your Hunting Rank is, unfortunately, to do every hunt as you encounter it. If you only do multiple-star-reward hunts, you'll end up having to backtrack and find all of the one-star-reward hunts you skipped. If you're doing the last hunt at a specific location, it might also speed things up marginally if you just go to the next tipster, since you can turn in hunts to *any* tipster.

Comment: Sadly, leveling hunter rank seems like something you either do in full, or ignore. There isnt an "easy" or "quick" way. The reason its about the only  thing left on my to do list.

Comment: @Mayshar Agreed on the all or nothing. It is annoying how there is only one trophy related to hunts

Comment: @Wondercricket at least it doesn't require maximum Hunter rank, though. The last trophy I got was maxing out fishing, which took quite a while.

Comment: @Wondercricket, I just verified that all hunts are required for Hunter Rank 10 :(

Comment: Yea, this game leaves out quite a bit of "hard" grinding that could have been trophies, Hunter Rank 10 is one of them im glad isnt a trophy